# Accessing parent level using Data::Visitor::Callback (Perl)

Tags: perl

This is a long-shot, but are there any perl developers out there who know anything about Data::Visitor::Callback?

I have a complex data structure that I am traversing.  Each time I find a hash that has a 'total' key, I need to build up a URL.  I have some of the data that I need to create these URLs but some of the data comes from higher up in the structure.

I don't think I can access the levels above and that makes it impossible to build my URLs.  I only just realised that I needed data from higher up the structure.

If I can't make Data::Visitor::Callback work for me, then it means rolling my own traversal code - which is a pain.

Data I am traversing is converted from the following JSON (the "count" keys are renamed to "total" as part of the conversion process):

```
[
        {
            "field": "field_name",
            "value": "A",
            "count": 647,
            "pivot": [
                {
                    "field": "field_name",
                    "value": "B",
                    "count": 618,
                    "pivot": [
                        {
                            "field": "field_name",
                            "value": "C1",
                            "count": 572
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "field_name",
                            "value": "C2",
                            "count": 266
                        },
                        {
                            "field": "field_name",
                            "value": "C3",
                            "count": 237
                        }
                    ]
                },
                ...
```

Once I get to the deepest level (C), I need both A and B values in order to construct my URLs.

Because Data::Visitor::Callback is acting on each leaf independently, I'm not sure that it 'knows' where in the structure it is.

All help very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I like this question, but it would help if you could explain (hopefully with code) where in the structure the data needs to come from, and perhaps any examples of code that you have tried.

Comment: Updated to include data structure (example)

Comment: Much better, but I don't see any hash keys named 'total'. Is there any way you can put an example how the two are related?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it better.  The JSON above is converted to a perl data structure and during that process, the "count" field names are translated to "total".

Comment: Ok. I'd edit the post to state exactly that, so it's clear to other readers.

Comment: Good point, will do.

Comment: @NickJHoran: You've given us very little to work with. Please show a self-contained sample of your data that we can test with, and the Perl code that you've tried

Comment: @NickJHoran: Please give an example of the URLs that you want to build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the JSON you posted is in the variable `$json_string`, the following code uses recursion to add the parents to all the children in the hash key `parent`, that way you can access the parents in your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $data = decode_json($json_string);

add_parent_to_children($_) for @$data;

sub add_parent_to_children {
  my $node        = shift;
  my $parent      = shift;
  $node->{parent} = $parent if $parent;
  if ($node->{pivot}) {
    add_parent_to_children($_, $node) for @{$node->{pivot}};
  }
}
```

Demo:

```
my $c3 = $data->[0]{pivot}[0]{pivot}[2];
print "$c3->{value}\n";                 # prints C3
print "$c3->{parent}{value}\n";         # prints B
print "$c3->{parent}{parent}{value}\n"; # prints A
```

Comment: I realise now that I was looking at this problem from the wrong point of view (from the child nodes back up).  Top-down approach makes total sense.  Good answer - thanks!